# How do I make the text in a text box affect code?

Tags: html, textbox

Pressing submit doesn't change the twitch streamer.

I've tried `<input>` but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<p> Twitch Streamer: <input type="text" name="ts" value="Ninja"><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </p>

<iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=randomguyontwitch"></iframe>
```

I want to make it whenever someone clicks "Submit", it will change "xQcOW" to whatever is in the text box. For this example "Ninja".

Comment: This cannot be done using purely HTML. Ideally, you could use either use JavaScript or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch your submit in order to change the streamer. The fetch is used by implementing [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php) into your code. If you've not used PHP before you can get started by using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/) or [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwJujkxYLZs&list=PL67D94BE42620925B).

This should do the trick:

```html
 <form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="ts" value="Ninja"><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Then you have to concat the value of ts with the iframe to something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=<?php echo $_GET["ts"] ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work smh? I typed in the code and everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of the textbox you'll need to add javascript to your code.
This should be your html file :

```
<p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

    function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById("myText").value = "whatever you want";
    }

</script>
```

You can use the same principle in your code. You change the `<input type="submit">` to `<button></button>`. Use `onclick` function for javascript.

Comment: Please could you try to implement this into the OP's code? This will only get the `val` from the input type and won't append it into the iFrames URL.

Comment: the `Iframe` you have added is a video so you want to change it to text?